# XML data shows in source not in browsers

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using the following code to get XML but when I echo the result it shows nothing in the browser but shows it in the source.

```
$enc = urlencode('SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner=****ID******');
$contents = file_get_contents("https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=$enc");

echo  $contents;
```

HERE IS THE PHP PAGE  [My Test Page](http://linguacademy.com/xml_test.php)

Once I get that figured out I need to prep $contents for simpleXML but I am not sure if I am doing it right?

```
$xml = <<<XML;
$xml .=$contents;
$xml .=XML;

echo $xml;
```

So to sum it up:

Thanks for you help with Issue #1 butI am not completely clear how to prepare a variable that contains XML for simpleXML. is the `<<<XML` and the `XML;` required?

Issue #2 How to add wrap the variable in the `<<<XML   and XML; tags?`

Comment: Some browsers decide not to show XML. I don't know if that's something you can really control.

Comment: It's not a deal breaker.... I just want to make sure that doesnt mess up simpleXML.

Comment: you also need to change your content type if you want to have it display properly `header('Content-type: application/xml');`

Comment: it shouldnt fuss with simple xml at all so long as the xml youre loading is well formed

Comment: @prodigitalson Well the XML is coming from Facebook and it looks like its formatted.

Comment: You don't need the `<<<XML` and `XML;` delimiters. They are for big strings with quotes and stuff. All you have is a variable. No point in wrapping it in another (identical) variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your web server is delivering the page as `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8`. This forces the browser to treat the content as HTML, and most of your elements aren't valid HTML elements.

Once you sort that out, IE and Firefox should display the XML directly, while Google Chrome might need a bit of [assistance](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cfphnlpadcinhoebfooghjoknlifphjb).

Comment: A much better XML viewer for chrome (IMO) is https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gbammbheopgpmaagmckhpjbfgdfkpadb?hl=en